# Why is Z3 giving me unsat for the following formula?

Tags: z3, z3py

I have the following formula and Python code trying to find the largest *n* satisfying some property P:

```
x, u, n, n2 = Ints('x u n n2')
def P(u):
    return Implies(And(2 <= x, x <= u), And(x >= 1, x <= 10))

nIsLargest = ForAll(n2, Implies(P(n2), n2 <= n))
exp = ForAll(x, And(P(n), nIsLargest))

s = SolverFor("LIA") 
s.reset()
s.add(exp)
print(s.check())
if s.check() == sat:
    print(s.model())
```

My expectation was that it would return n=10, yet Z3 returns unsat. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the optimization API incorrectly; and your question is a bit confusing since your predicate `P` has a free variable `x`: Obviously, the value that maximizes it will depend on both `x` and `u`.

Here's a simpler example that can get you started, showing how to use the API correctly:

```py
from z3 import *

def P(x):
    return And(x >= 1, x <= 10)

n = Int('n')
opt = Optimize()
opt.add(P(n))
maxN = opt.maximize(n)

r = opt.check()
print(r)
if r == sat:
    print("maxN =", maxN.value())
```

This prints:

```
sat
maxN = 10
```

Hopefully you can take this example and extend it your use case.

Comment: The free variable x in P is always in the scope of a universal quantifier. This is the actual expression that is sent to the solver:
`exp =  
    ForAll(x,
           And(Implies(And(x >= 2, x <= n),
                       And(x >= 1, x <= 10)),
               ForAll(n2,
                      Implies(Implies(And(x >= 2, x <= n2),
                                      And(x >= 1, x <= 10)),
                              n2 <= n))))`     
I tried to do my problem using Optimize but I get unsat and a _WARNING: optimization with quantified constraints is not supported_.

Comment: My problem seems almost identical to the one posed in here: [https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1711], which is unsupported. However, I am still at a loss to understand why what I have written doesn't work since I don't use Optimize

Comment: Think about what it means to satisfy a quantified formula: It'll be unsat even if there's a single element in the entire domain of its argument if it is false for it. That's the basic reason. You might want to look at the generated SMTLib (using `s.sexpr()`) to see the formula as it's seen by z3.

Comment: Ah, looking at it afresh,  see where I was mistaken. The "\A x" over the implication flips to "\E x" over the antecedent since x doesn't occur in the consequent. Once I moved it into the P predicate, everything worked - I didn't need the Optimize class. Anyway thanks for the reminder that I need to be more careful!